# input number in html that is not an integer

Tags: html

I have a div where I want the user to input a number that is between 0.05 and 0.5. I did it this way:

```
<input id="TS_dist" class="tableButton" type="number" maxlength="1" size="5" value="0.2" />
```

The problem is that when I am puting a value I cannot use the zero, it is not working, the . is not either. Only 1-9 numbers are accepted.

My browser is firefox.

Do you have any idea what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: the first thing you're doing wrong is not defining your own requirements. For example, is 0.1234567890000 between 0.05 & 0.5, or not? and how about 0.050000?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the value increases/decreases by 1. Add a `step` attribute to change this behaviour:

```
<input step="0.05" id="TS_dist" class="tableButton" type="number" maxlength="1" size="5" value="0.2" />
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uh44h3y8/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try adding, step="any" in this input.

Answer (score 0):

add `step=0.1`on `<input>` field that will work